# Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

May I know why I get this error, when I try to bring up my app in visual studio. Would it be because of missing installation of of 'ASP.NET web development' or '.NET cross-platform development' workloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probablly are missing .net core runtime

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

Comment: My project target framework is net5.0. Should I go for net5.0? Above shows 6.0.

Comment: yes you neet version 5 - i does not known if 6 is backwards compatible
so you have visual studio 2022 you create new blazor project then click run and see this message?

Comment: Just a quick question, doesn't it get installed with ASP.NET and web development workload or .NET cross-platform development workload in VS. Or it only has to be downloaded separately, even if we have the above workloads in VS. Thank you.

Comment: visual studio install it itself but vscode no so try install and You will known - error says that this is missing imho.